# how to check depending on hour base

Tags: php, time

I have a field that has time and date in following format

```
2010-03-26 10:06:11
```

What I need is that if this time is within 4 hours of current time then show but if its over 4 hour then done show this record.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ts = strtotime($value);
$curtime = time();
if (($ts > $curtime - 4*3600) && ($ts < $curtime + 4*3600)) {
    //show
}
else
    //don't show
```

You can also make a one-side comparison by choosing only one of the conditions (it isn't clear what you want from the question).